# Access another java file in a java file

Tags: java, package

I know this question has been asked and answered a number of times. But I somehow am not able to get this right. I have a package having the following structure

```
model/
   InputDetails.java
   RelationDetails.java
```

Now the file `RelationDetails` has the following structure:

```
package model;
public class RelationDetails {
     ....
}
```

And the file `InputDetails` has the following structure

```
package model;
public class InputDetails {
    .....
}
```

Now I have compiled the `RelationDetails.java` file that creates a `RelationDetails.class` file in the same directory.
But when I try to compile the `InputDetails.java` file, It shows the error

```
Symbol not found
```

wherever `RelationDetails` has been used. Where am I going wrong??

Comment: `Where am I going wrong??` You need to go deeper...

Comment: Please tell us which command you executed and from which directory.

Comment: Please give more details and elaborate the error "Symbol Not Found"

Comment: provide details how the `InputDetails` is referencing the other

Comment: go to the current directory and execute > javac *.java

Comment: @Duncan I was in the model directory itself..I first executed "javac RelationDetails.java" which compiled successfully and created the class file. I then executed "javac InputDetails.java" which created the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using an IDE like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) or [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). They will do the compiling for you. Or use Ant, Gradle or Maven to compile. I am a professional Java developer and I cannot remember the last time I used `javac` from the command line. There's no need for it.

If you insist on using `javac` directly, either compile both files *together* from the appropriate source folder (the directory above "model").:

```
javac "model/InputDetails.java" "model/RelationDetails.java"
```

Or, if you want to compile them separately:

```
javac -classpath . "model/InputDetails.java"
javac -classpath . "model/RelationDetails.java"
```

The `-classpath .` bit adds the current folder to the classpath for the `javac` executable, so it can find the previously compiled class and you won't get the 'Symbol not found' errors.

Comment: Yes!! This did the job..Thanks..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ pwd
/tmp/model

$ ls
InputDetails.java  RelationDetails.java

$ javac  InputDetails.java  RelationDetails.java

$ ls *.class
InputDetails.class  RelationDetails.class
```

Comment: From which directory? Rather than rushing to post an answer, why not wait and see what the OP did wrong and correct them?

Comment: Ok, *now* your answer may be of some use to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I am just tried in my eclipse nothing will be showing errors, better to user Eclipse or STS they will help you like this problems easily I think  so..

Answer (score -1):

compile with fully qualifier name.

```
javac model\YourClass.java
```